# Trino, Iceberg and ADLS / Azure

Tags: azure, trino

I'd like to use Trino with Iceberg Tables and Azure ADLS/Blob Storage instead of S3.

I was able to successfully connect to S3 like

```
connector.name=iceberg
iceberg.catalog.type=jdbc
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.catalog-name=test
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.driver-class=org.postgresql.Driver
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/iceberg
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.connection-user=user
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.connection-password=pwd
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.default-warehouse-dir=s3://mybucket
```

Now I'd like to do the same with Azure, as our main cloud platform is Azure. I tried some combinations of

```
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.default-warehouse-dir=abfss://test@bla.dfs.core.windows.net
```

but did not succeed so far. Has someone ever successfully connected Trino to Iceberg Tables on Azure (without Hive). We would like to use the REST Catalog (JDBC is just here for testing). There is nearly no documentation on how to use Azure with Trino.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out by myself. Here we go:

```
connector.name=iceberg
iceberg.catalog.type=jdbc
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.catalog-name=test
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.driver-class=org.postgresql.Driver
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/iceberg
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.connection-user=user
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.connection-password=pwd
iceberg.jdbc-catalog.default-warehouse-dir=abfs://coldasice@coldasice.dfs.core.windows.net
hive.azure.abfs-storage-account = coldasice
hive.azure.abfs-access-key = KGKGGSDJF...
```